# iOS: How to offer directions from annotation view?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

Basically what I'm wondering is how to offer the user an option to get directions in Maps from an annotation (like that little car icon inside of the annotation that opens up directions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use left/right callout accessory view to add your icon and when you tap on it you can implement your direction logic.